# How to run a php file out of the www folder that is on the same web server?

Tags: php, html, forms, security, web

Say i have a basic html page where a simple form is set up. When the user submits the form I would like a php script that is stored out of the www folder (for security reasons) but on the same server to then validate that none of the form's fields have been left empty. This data could then be sent to a server to be stored in a database.

My question is how would I actually access the php script as it is out of the root directory? I know about get and post requests but I don't know how I could point to the file out of the root folder securely. This is because the user could look at the onsubmit function in the html file and find out the location of the php file and the download it. Is that possible? I am not even sure with that...

I have done a bit of searching around and am sure this question is answered but with my basic knowledge of PHP couldn't wrap my head around it. Could anyone please post a simple answer. It would be much appreciated.

Comment: PHP should be below the root directory as the web server will run the processes necessary to execute the PHP.

Comment: As long as the server is properly configured, you can't download the source code of a PHP file. Accessing it just gives you its output.

Comment: You cant access it using the url, that is the whole point, instead add a file that `includes` it and then access that file.  The main reason to have a file outside of the web root, is because you may need other things setup too, for example the file can't run on it's own and would create errors that may output stuff you don't want anyone to see, i'm sure there are other reasons. But that is the first to come to mind, I use that setup also for cron jobs ( automated background jobs ) because no one needs to run them from the url.

Answer (score 0):

> When the user submits the form I would like a php script that is stored out of the www folder (for security reasons) but on the same server to then validate that none of the form's fields have been left empty.

The point of storing a PHP file outside the webroot is so that it can never be requested by a client.

You typically do this with PHP files which contain sensitive data, such as configuration scripts that include passwords for databases. That way, even if something goes horribly wrong with the configuration of the server and it serves up PHP files directly (exposing the source code) instead of executing the PHP in them (replacing the source code with the output of the script), then the data is safe.

If you want to submit a form to a PHP script, then put that PHP script under the webroot.

Then, if it needs to access sensitive data (such as the database credentials) put them in a *seperate* PHP file, put that PHP file outside the webroot, and then `include()` it.